# How to do background animation in Angularjs on ng-repeat filter change?

Tags: css, angularjs, ng-animate

I want to add an animation for resizing to the background div when there are changes in ng-repeat filter. I can't find the way to do this because no css changes really happening during the process. Is this possible?

Simple example:

```
<div style="border: 1px solid black; width: 100px; transition: all 1s ease; background-color: green;">
  <p ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo:limit">{{item}}</p>
</div>
<button ng-click="changeLimit()">Change limit</button>
```

Here a simple codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PQbZNY

Comment: what background ?

Comment: Any background div for iterated list. Like this one: <div style="border: 1px solid black; width: 100px; transition: all 1s ease;">

Comment: well this is a border not background

Comment: Ok, I'll add background style to avoid confusion.